# Create Mojave Cocoa window programmatically in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-mojave, programmatically-created

I'm trying to create a minimal application in order for me to start a game engine from scratch. Here is the code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] init];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, false)
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

I would how to display a window without calling CFRunLoopRunInMode().

Xcode 10.1

MacOS 10.14.3

Comment: Have you read about how AppKit uses runloops? I think you can find a lot in the documentation to CFRunLoop and the pages it links.

Comment: You're eventually going to have to run the app's main event loop, but if you really want, you can try `[window display]`.

Comment: @Mats: I will read more, again.

Comment: @KenThomases: not working (you can test it yourself as all the code you need is posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the answer myself. The window does not appear unless it receives the nextEventMatchingMask: message. This is probably what triggers the window in a CFRunLoop and is what I wanted to know, although it would be nice if I could dig deeper. For now, I'm happy with the following solution.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
@autoreleasepool {
    // Create a default window
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] init];
    // Make it blue just for better visibility
    [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
    // Bring to front and make it key
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    // Custom run loop
    NSEvent* event;
    while(1) {
        do {
            event = [window nextEventMatchingMask:NSEventMaskAny]; //window shows now
            if ([event type] == NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown) {
                NSLog(@"Mouse down");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Something happened");
            }
        } while (event != nil);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I don't have a reference for that. I can only refer to this article: [Handmade Hero for mac](https://medium.com/@theobendixson/handmade-hero-osx-platform-layer-day-2-b26d6966e214) in which the window appears due to a similar method. That was not good enough for me because such a method involves NSApp, which I would like to avoid, if possible.

Comment: macOS 13.1, clang version 14.0.0 - the code is not working, no window appears.

Comment: Hi @vadim_hr. It has been a long time. I'm sorry I haven't seen this before. You can find my latest results here: https://github.com/antonioastorino/MacOS-Plotter-from-scratch

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not a Cocoa app.

You need to use the Xcode template to create a simple, one window, Cocoa app. That template will include a `main()` that starts the AppKit (`NSApplicationMain(argc,argv);`). This function performs the (approximately) 5,000 little things that make a Cocoa app run.

In the app bundle's `Info.plist` you either define a custom subclass of `NSApplication` to run your app or, much more commonly, in `MainMenu.xib` you define a custom `NSApplicationDelegate` object.

Once the AppKit has initialized and is ready to start your application, both of those objects will receive a message that you can override and add your custom startup code.

The standard template does all of that, so just use it to create a new project and then add your code to `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Comment: I don't want to use a template. That's what I meant with "programmatically" in the title.

Comment: I thought you went you wanted to create the window programmatically. What you're asking about is creating the *application* programmatically; that's a whole different kettle of fish, and one I don't have an answer to because I'm not sure it's even possible (to create a Cocoa app without an app bundle).